# SSRS join multiple Datasets, but same data elements

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can I make a dataset for multiple tables and populate each element in the report based on if a FK value exists in the table?
Here is the situation...
I need to populate a report with just the most current data for each record. In the structure of the database, each subsequent record is in a different table. 
So if John says he likes cookies when we call him, and then we call him later and he says he likes Ice cream, Table1 has John and Cookies, table2 has John and IceCream. Up to 5 attempts, so tables 1-5. I need to check all of the tables, but only return the most current. So I need to check tables 3-5 for John, but only return IceCream for table2. 
Following this example, I would need a report that is just "[Name] currently likes [Dessert]."
All five tables have the exact same structure (but the first table has 2 additional columns) and same column names. 
I'm returning around 200 data elements, so selecting them all into a temp table if they are not in a subsequent table will make the query incredibly long, and, apparently, too long for SSRS since it got truncated when I tried.

Comment: That is a horrible data model to deal with...if you are still able to, change the data structure you are using. 5 tables like this is folly and will cause much reporting pain.  Can still work with it though...Is "most current" in your example simply the highest numbered table that person has an entry in?  I'm tempted to say your best solution will involve a view that unions the 5 tables together.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view to organize your data into a more queryable table.

I can't really tell you how to do create your view since I don't know the data model, but you could union results from all the tables.

Then, the query in the report will be easier to write.

Good luck!
Alex